# How to fix error: memory read failed for 0x0

Tags: swift4.2, xcode10.1

I have clicked login button and the message throw in notification center and a country picker opened and when I click on button in country picker log in view Controller must be opened but it throws an error:

> memory read failed for 0x0 ........

this error comes in between obtaining controller object and present.
what should I do now??

I am using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4

```
@objc func showSpinningWheel(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if whichbuttonclick == true
    {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else
    {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Register", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I expect it to jump over login controller but it throws error.

Comment: The error is probably in how you configured the notification registration. But you have not shown that code.

Comment: Please check this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73976108/1758701

Answer (score 0):

This is how i add Notification Observer :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(self.showSpinningWheel(:)),
    name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "opencontrollermessagenotification"),
    object: nil
)
    
@objc func showSpinningWheel( notification: NSNotification)
{
    if whichbuttonclick == true {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Login", sender: self)
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Register", sender: self)
    }
}
```

and This is how i Post it :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "opencontrollermessagenotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```