# Xcode error: memory read failed for 0x0, no stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, stack-overflow

Xcode debug my app, I find some thread no stack, only 0x00000000 (but not crash).  (In fact, there are similar crashes on the line in app store.)

Stack info:
error: memory read failed for 0x0
I think stack overflow, so I try use tool "Address Sanitizer", but not found too.

Why is this happening, xcode no stack?

[image]

Comment: It happens that I may have a similar bug to this.  In most cases esp. when you can not figure out the culprit of the bug in the code, it is more likely that it is from "Data race" or multi-threading issues.  Please try the test with the awesome tool "Thread Sanitizer" which the only Xcode in the world can give you.  I fixed this type of bugs with the great tool Apple provides with Xcode!   Only God (Jesus) may help you when you can not do it on your own.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this crash happened at the beginning. I turned off the "Debug executable" in Product -> Edit Scheme -> Info tab, and it worked. In the background it applied the following modification to the `xcscheme` file:

```
  selectedDebuggerIdentifier = ""
  selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn"
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on pods under runner and update every pod at minimum deployment ios to 12.0

[you can in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1T83.jpg)