# Memory read failed for 0x0 in a game loop, need a proper debugging method

Tags: c, debugging, lldb, game-loop

My program crashes somewhere during a game loop at variable times independent of input events. I am looking for a suitable debugging method that I can use to find the problem in my code.
When I fire up my lldb debugger against the executable, run it without set breakpoints, I get the following output after some time, when the program crashes:

```
Process 86823 stopped
* thread #2, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000001
error: memory read failed for 0x0
Target 0: (smoke) stopped.
```

This tells me, that I am trying to read something from a bad memory address. The issue is, I am not sure how to pinpoint that in my code, as this may or may not occur in a given cycle of a game loop. So just setting a breakpoint is problematic. What is the proper debugging method in this case?

Comment: I was just reading about assertions. Maybe that is what I am missing here. Will set a few up in what I think are key locations in my code

Comment: have you tried compiling with symbols and run a backtrace?

Comment: @AhmedMasud I do compile with a -g flag. WIll look into how to run a backtrace

Comment: @AhmedMasud when I run a backtrace, I get asm instructions, instead of line numbers in my source file, even though I compile with a -g flag, and it normally, loads the symbols. Output I am getting:

`->  0x7fff201ccd29 <+41>: cmpq   (%r11), %rsi`


Is there a way I can "map" that instruction to a relevant line in my C code?

Comment: The backtrace command should give you the call stack, including file names and line numbers. If you see just assembly, the illegal access is in a library's function, but your code calls this.

Comment: Frame 0 is bogus (the address is 0x1, which is not a mapped address on macOS).  So somebody is calling through a function pointer that is not valid.  The memory read that caused the error is the system trying to fetch instructions at that not-valid address.  You should be able to tell from the stack track what that function pointer might be.  You can also look at the stack for the first instance of code in your application, and use the `f` command to set the frame there, and poke around at locals (`v`) to see if you can find the bad pointer originating in your code.

Comment: BTW, if you have an address and want to know what library that address comes from, use `image lookup -va <ADDRESS>`.  That will tell you everything lldb knows about that address...

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73976108/1758701